# Calculating values from arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to make a program that calculates insurance costs. It takes numbers from an array, for example, ('%','100%200%300%400%500%600%700',400,.3). 400 being the max, and .3 being the percent, it has to take the data values and tell which one is more than the max. It tells how much the number is over the max, multiplies it by the percent, then adds it to the total. P.S. I added "index" because I am not allowed to directly use i++. I have to use a For loop with a nested If, should I be putting an Else in there?

The results I am getting are "undefined" and I cannot figure out why. Do you see any errors or something I can change?

```
function paidInsuranceCost(delimiter, delimitedListProductCosts, maxPriceForNoInsuranceCost, insuranceCostPercent) {
    var newArray = delimitedListProductCosts.split(delimiter);
    var total, index, i;
    for (i = 0; newArray[i] < newArray.length; index) {
        if (i < maxPriceForNoInsuranceCost) {
            index = index++;
            var result = i - maxPriceForNoInsuranceCost;
            total = (total + result) * insuranceCostPercent;
        };
     };
     return total;
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; index) {`

Comment: The only way total would be undefined is if the loop ran the block inside it zero times or the `if (i < maxPriceForNoInsuranceCost) {` was always false. NaN is a possibility from the `total` assignment statement you have, but undefined isn't AFAIK.

Comment: This seems like a homework. I recommend putting a breakpoint in Inspector Tools and debugging the script on top of the hints that @BenAtkin already gave.

Comment: please review the formula and add an step-by-step calculation of the wanted result.

Comment: total is never initialised

Comment: btw, `result` is always negative.

Answer (score 0):

After getting more [help](https://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/383677-beginner-help.html) from somebody (maybe the OP?), the whole problem is the following:

> Your company sells products to customers. For each product the insurance is free up to a certain product cost.
>
> Product cost above that maximum is the basis for insurance cost.
>
> Calculate the total cost of insurance for a list of products sold.

You need a check if the actual value is above of the included insurance value, then the delta is used and multiplied by the given value and added to `total`.

```js
function paidInsuranceCost(delimiter, delimitedListProductCosts, maxPriceForNoInsuranceCost, insuranceCostPercent) {
    var newArray = delimitedListProductCosts.split(delimiter).map(Number),
        total = 0, i;

    for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        if (newArray[i] > maxPriceForNoInsuranceCost) {
            total += (newArray[i]- maxPriceForNoInsuranceCost ) * insuranceCostPercent;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(paidInsuranceCost('%', '100%200%300%400%500%600%700', 400, 0.3));
console.log(paidInsuranceCost('$', '200$345$100$500', 300, 0.1));
```